# What is the best way to have many images and (thumbnails?) for one entity?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, symfony

I am using PHP and MySQL ( via the framework Symfony 2) to create a website to show some bikes of my collection. I would like to store as much images as needed for one bike.

So I was thinking that a good way to do that is to have my **Bike entity** and a **Picture entity** and to link the Bike entity with the Picture entity by a **one-to-many relation**.

So, the Picture entity would look like this :

```
id     bike_id    title   path
```

Is this the best way to do it ? Thanks a lot for your advice.
**EDIT** : **About storing thumbnails ..**
Do we have to store thumbnails version too ? As I will display many pictures in one page, I read that reducing the picture with width and height was a bad practice and it was better to store a reduced version of the picture.

So the Picture entity would rather looks like this ? :

```
id     bike_id    title    path     path_thumbnail
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though you could
 simplify naming the images and avoid naming conflicts by scrapping `path` and storing images as `{id}.jpg`.

**UPDATE** - from your edit, I think you miss the point of what I'm saying about naming images. I suggest you *don't* store any image or thumbnail URLs at all. Instead, just have a table that looks like:

```
Id    BikeId    Title
277   123       "Cool picture"
```

Then name all your images and thumbnail files according to their `Id`. In the above example, the "Cool picture" files could be called **/img/277.jpg** and **/img/277-thumb.jpg**.

That way you don't have to store lots of file names in the database, and also there won't be any issues with file names clashing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `One to many` Relationship between Entity and Pictures like this

Picture.php

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bike", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bike_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $Bike;
```

Then you can have one row for each image and you can use [symfony image](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) upload as you would do for single image